# Roblox, Dont change text and Image dont change

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I have a problem with changing images and text here is the script:

```
--Image Change(localScript)
local Player = game:GetService("Players")

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local imageLabel = script.Parent.Parent.ImageTag
local userID = player.UserId
local thumbType = Enum.ThumbnailType.HeadShot
local thumbSize = Enum.ThumbnailSize.Size420x420

local content, isReady = Player:GetUserThumbnailAsync(userID, thumbType, thumbSize)

while wait() do
    imageLabel.Image = content
end
```

```
--Text Change(localScript)

local textLabel = script.Parent.Parent.NameTag

local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

while wait() do
    textLabel.Text = player.Name
end
```

```
--Passport Clone(Script)

local passport = game.ReplicatedStorage.Passport

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    if plr:IsInGroup(14472135) then
        local passportClone = passport:Clone()
        passportClone.Parent = game.StarterPack
    end
end)
```

When the passport is cloned then I can see my name and image but other player see nothing.

Any Suggestion thanks

Comment: What is the problem? What do you expect to happen? What is actually happening? What errors are you getting?

Comment: The problem is that I get no error When the passport spawn then the text will be not changed and an image will not change and I don't understand why have I to make a local script? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume your problem is that the image and text are only changing for the player who has the passport and not for others. If so, you only need to change two scripts: Image Change, and Text Change.

Here is what I think should work for the scripts.

Image Change

```
--Image Change(Script)
    game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
        local Player = game:GetService("Players")
    
    
        local imageLabel = script.Parent.Parent.ImageTag
        local userID = player.UserId
        local thumbType = Enum.ThumbnailType.HeadShot
        local thumbSize = Enum.ThumbnailSize.Size420x420
        
        local content, isReady = Player:GetUserThumbnailAsync(userID, thumbType, thumbSize)
    
        while wait() do
            imageLabel.Image = content
        end
    end)
```

Text Change

```
  --Text Change(Script)
    game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
        local textLabel = script.Parent.Parent.NameTag
    
        while wait() do
            textLabel.Text = player.Name
        end
    end)
```

Let me know if these don't work but they shoud.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment, but sadly this is not working.
Here is a foto: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1016372634407153764/1027222978632626266/unknown.png

How can i fix this? 

Thanks for your answer